# How to restrict capacity of PointNodes in a Network

Tags: anylogic

I have a network of Path and PointNode objects. I want to send a Transporter to a certain node in the network. In that node the transporter should stop. Now I send a second Transporter to that same node. The second Transporter can reach the target node (and drives physically into the first Transporter). A transporter in a node seems not to occupy part of the path. Nodes seem to have unlimited capacity. I want the first Transporter I sent to the node just to stop at the node an still occupy the path, so that when sending a second transporter it can not reach its final position at the node unless the first Transporter leaves to a next target.
Any idea how to model this appropriately in AnyLogic? For me it seems to be a simple buffering and I do not understand why nodes have unlimited capacity in Anylogic.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

"Nodes and paths are space markup elements that define the locations of agents in the space". To define the capacity, you can take a look at incorporating the ResourcePool and related constructs (cease, release, delay, service) in the Process Modeling Library.